# Regex ony captures one group or the other, not both

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use a regex to capture two names groups. My code seems correct when I want to capture a single group but for some reason when adding the 2nd group to my finditer call it returns no results.

https://regex101.com/r/FDpAuU/1

### Sample text:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
```

### 1st Capture Group:

```
text = """146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
    197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
    156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701"""
item = re.findall("(?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})",text )
item
```

### 2nd Capture Group:

```
text = """146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
    197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
    156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701"""
item = re.findall("(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)",text )
item
```

How can I combine both capture groups into a single call of findall (or finditer) ?

Answer (score 2):

Join the groups with `.*?`:

```
(?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/FDpAuU/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<host>                  group and capture to \k<host>:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \k<host>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<user_name>             group and capture to \k<user_name>:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \k<user_name>
```

Comment: is .*? actually a join? Everything I have read online indicates *? is a lazy modifier? I'm struggling to understand how it works (although it does work, thanks!)

Comment: @ShuN I am sorry, I meant join the two groups. Same as "insert" the ".*?" between the groups. It is required because there is some text between the parts you want to extract. You know, these parts do not go one after another immediately.

Comment: Understood, thank you. Step 1 for me should be to full match the entire string that I want to parse capture groups from. Adding the .* will indicate that there is text between host and user_name in my string. Adding the '?' tells my regex to stop matching after the '-' character, at which point the user_name is captured.

Comment: @ShuN Adding '?' to '.*' says to regex engine to match the least amount of characters as possible before the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is you you match full string while capturing both the groups you have defined:

1. Use capture groups inside 2 different [positive lookahead conditions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
2. Place a lazy quantifier and word boundary before your groups

Suggested regex:

```sh
^(?=.*?\b(?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(?=.*?\b(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)).+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/whHRWC/1)